# How to turn off default Mouse Event Handlers in ILNumerics PlotCube?

Tags: c#, plot, ilnumerics

I'm using the ILNumerics Math Library to create some 2D Plots. To display the data I use the ILPlotCube Class. I would like to turn off the default behavior of the EventHandler for MouseDoubleClick events, because I would like to implement my own. Is that possible?

Here's some more context:

The default event handler of an ILPlotCube for MouseDoubleClick events resets the view to default values. Usually this works quite well, but there seems to be a problem with very small x- and y-values. When I add a linePlot with very small y-values the limits of the plots are automatically set to YMax=0.525 and YMin=-0.525. Unfortunately, that's not what I want. So, I set the values myself after adding the linePlot and the plot looks exactly how I'd like to have it. Great... but: if I double click on the scene it uses the default (0.525) values again. Dough! That's why I would like to turn off or overwrite this behavior.

Any ideas?

```
   private void ilPanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var scene = new ILScene();
        //data with very small "y-values"
        ILArray<float> line1 = new float[,] { 
                    {0.0f,  1.0f, 2.0f }, 
                    {2.042166e-08f,  2.070141e-08f , 2.042166e-08f} };

        var linePlot1 = new ILLinePlot(line1.T,
           lineColor: Color.Blue,
           lineWidth: 3,
           markerStyle: MarkerStyle.Dot);
        //Create Plot Cube
        var plotCube = new ILPlotCube();

        plotCube.Add(linePlot1);
        //plotCube.Plots.Limits.YMax is now 0.525
        //plotCube.Plots.Limits.YMin is now -0.525

        //manually set the value
        float maxY = 0.0f;
        using (ILScope.Enter())
        {
            var aPos = linePlot1.Line.Positions.Storage["1;:"];
            maxY = ILMath.max(aPos).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        plotCube.Plots.Limits.YMax = maxY;
        plotCube.Plots.Limits.YMin = 0.0f;
        var plot = scene.Add(plotCube);

        ilPanel1.Scene = scene;
    }
```

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All nodes in ILNumerics provide access to the common mouse handlers which you can use to provide your own logic - or to simply disable existing individual handlers. In your case, you can override the double click handler for the plot cube:

```
// ....

plotCube.MouseDoubleClick += (_e, _a) => {
    _a.Cancel = true; 
};
// you may want disable zoom and pan as well? 
plot.AllowZoom = false;
plot.AllowPan = false; 

// continue with your code here...
ilPanel1.Scene = scene;
```

The mouse handlers in ILNumerics are actually very flexible and powerful. See the documentation here: http://ilnumerics.net/mouse-events.html

@Edit: for your situation, the [ILPlotCube.AutoScaleOnAdd](http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/?topic=html/P_ILNumerics_Drawing_Plotting_ILPlotCube_AutoScaleOnAdd.htm) property might also be of interest. It determines, if the plot cube limits are to be recomputed once a new plot has been added to the plot cube. You might find `false` more convenient.